# Can sibling functions share the same generic type?

Tags: typescript

Consider two functions `init` and `query`:

```js
function init<Schema = any>() {
  // ...
}

function query<Schema = any>(): Schema { 
  return 1 as Schema
}
```

Now if we run `init`:

```
type Foo = {bar: 1}

init<Foo>()
```

I would love to make it so that the result of `query` is *automatically* inferred as the type we passed into `init`.

```
const res = query()
// Goal: type of res is _inferred_ as `Foo`
```

I am *pretty* sure this is not possible. One way I could solve it, is by having `init` return something of type S, and passing that to query. Is there any other way?

Comment: Use a factory to create related functions

Comment: Doesn't sound possible, both functions are completely independent, the only way you could achieve this is to make them related by either wrapping them inside a generic class and return that generic type in `query` or returning them inside an object in a generic function (which is almost the same as the class suggestion).

Comment: What should happen if you call `query()` after `init<Foo>(); init<Bar>();`? This is impossible for a type checker to decide.

Comment: Why does `init()` need a generic definition at all? It has no parameters or return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way for two sibling functions to share the same generic. The type checker cannot make this inference statically.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions appear completely unrelated. They could be in completely separate modules for all we know.

If you want them together, group them using either a class...

```ts
class SomeClass<Schema> {
  init() {
    // ...
  }

  query(): Schema {
    return 1 as Schema;
  }
}

const instance = new SomeClass<Foo>();
instance.init();
const res = instance.query();
```

or use a factory function

```ts
function factory <Schema>() {
  return {
    init() {
      // ...
    },
    query(): Schema {
      return 1 as Schema;
    }
  };
}

const { init, query } = factory<Foo>();
```

Comment: Or have `init` return `query`.

Comment: @Bergi OP's `init()` doesn't return anything though why it needs a generic with no parameters or return value eludes me

Comment: Yeah I'm just guessing what the functions do based on the names, and changing `init` to return the other function (instead of having it as a sibling) is one of the many solutions. It also prevents calling `query` without calling `init` first, and prevents calling `init` multiple times (per `query` function), and gets rid of the presumed global state they share.

Comment: @Bergi I thought `init()` could probably make a good class constructor which easily works in with the above suggestions